# Stochastic assignment problem

Tags: probability, optimization, asymptotics

Given an $n \times n$ real matrix $C$, we can try to maximize 
$$\Phi(C, \pi) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} C_{i,\pi(i)}
$$
over $\pi \in S_n$, the set of all permutations on $n$ objects. What can one say about this problem if the $C_{ij}$ are random variables? Numerical evidence indicates that for normally distributed independent entries $C_{ij} \sim N(0,1)$, the optimal value  $argmax_\pi \Phi$ of the objective function has a mean of about $.67 (\log n)^.82$ and a standard deviation approximately equal to $.84/\sqrt{n \log n}$, if $n \ge 10$ or so.

Is this known? Is there a theory that implies these observations and makes them more precise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking about the optimal value of the random assignment problem, which has received quite a lot of study in the past couple of decades.  Most of the work has been with uniform$[0,1]$ or exponential$(1)$ random variables, though, and with minimums.  Perhaps this is because the uniform and exponential cases have proved easiest to analyze.  While I don't think there has been much explicit work on the case in which costs are $N(0,1)$, we can piece some of the results together to say that the expected value you're looking for is $$E[\Phi_n] \sim A \sqrt{\log n},$$ for some constant $A$.

Define $$L_n = \min_{\pi \in S_n} \sum_i C_{i,\pi(i)}.$$  Frenk, van Houweninge, and Rinnooy Kan ("[Order statistics and the linear assignment problem](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/48626/orderstatisticsl00fren.pdf?sequence=1)," *Computing* 39 (2), 165-174, 1987) proved that under some mild conditions on the cumulative distribution function $F$ that, for some constant $C$ that depends on $F$, $$E[L_n] \sim C n F^{-1}(1/n).$$  Since the normal pdf is symmetric we can apply [asymptotic estimates](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.17#iii) for $F^{-1}(1-1/n)$ (i.e., the maximum rather than the minimum) so that when costs are $N(0,1)$, for some constant $A$, $$E[\Phi_n] \sim A \sqrt{\log n},$$
which is not far from what your numerical evidence says.  (If $C$ turns out to be $1$ in the normal case, then we would have $A = \sqrt{2}$.)

---

For the exponential$(1)$ distribution, Aldous ("[The $\zeta(2)$ limit in the random assignment problem](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0010/0010063v1.pdf)," *Random Structures and Algorithms* 18 (4), 381-418, 2001), proved that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[L_n] = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$  Aldous notes that his result holds for distributions with the same density at $0$ (assuming this exists and is positive), so we have the same limiting value if costs are uniform$[0,1]$.  This was followed a few years later by independent work from Linusson and Wästlund ("[A proof of Parisi's conjecture on the random assignment problem](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~wastlund/Parisi.pdf)," *Probability Theory and Related Fields* 128 (3), 419-400, 2004) and Nair, Prabhakar, and Sharma ("[Proofs of the Parisi and Coppersmith-Sorkin random assignment conjectures](http://www.stanford.edu/~balaji/papers/05proofsof.pdf)," *Random Structures and Algorithms* 27 (4), 413-444, 2005) proving that in the exponential$(1)$ case $$E[L_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}.$$

---

For more, see the recent survey paper by Krokhmal and Pardalos ("[Random assignment problems](http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~krokhmal/pdf/random-assignment-problems.pdf)," *European Journal of Operational Research* 194, 1-17, 2009).  There are some results given there on variances.  For instance, in the exponential$(1)$ case, it appears that $$\sigma^2(L_n) = \frac{4\zeta(2) - 4\zeta(3)}{n}  + O(n^{-2}).$$

Comment: thank you, that is exactly the kind of information that I had hoped for. The result by Frenk etc. is perhaps more relevant to my question, since the minimization problem for the case of distributions that are supported on $(0,\infty)$ does not have to deal with the effects of infinite tails.